# How to pass the password of two servers in shell

Tags: shell-script

While I am copying the files from one server to another server using the scp command while I am running in PuTTY it was asking for the password of two server machines. Is there any other way to copy the files without a password or with passwords means how can I pass in the command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By far the best way is to use public/private key pair authentication. If you don't already have a key pair on the machine from which you are running putty you should create one using puttygen, save the private key locally and provide the path to it in putty at Connection/SSH/Auth, then save the public key in the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file of the machine to which you are connecting with putty. Then you need to save the public key of this machine (probably at ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub) in the ~/.ssh/authorized_keys file of the user & machine to which it connects to run scp.

Comment: Thanks for quick response, and am not having rsa to use so can use please suggest more, I used the same script to copy the file from one server to another server but that time it is not asking for password but where as am trying to copy to different server it is asking for password...
example: am working in server 1 i need to copy the files to server 2 and server 3 .. for server2 it not asking for password where as for server it is asking for passsword.

Comment: if you are not using some other security mechanism, any machine should ask for a password when you connect with `scp`, if it doesn't then its security is seriously lacking.

Comment: can you suggest how to write the command to pass  the password in putty

Comment: to do this 'properly' you use another piece of software by the same guy called `pageant` - available at http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html. But also see http://superuser.com/questions/44106/is-there-a-way-to-auto-login-in-putty-with-a-password.

Comment: ok Thank you :) so in shell script we can't pass the password right ...

Comment: there might be a way to do it if you follow the second link in my previous comment, but it's not recommended because it involves saving a password which is a security risk in itself.

Comment: ok can you suggest any command which need  copy the files from server a to sever b and server c

Comment: are all machines running linux? if you are using `putty` I assume at least one machine is running windows?

Comment: all machine running in linux only

Comment: if you don't want to use `ssh` you could try `telnet` - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15807122/telnet-file-transfer-between-two-linux-machines - or `ftp` - see http://superuser.com/questions/323214/how-to-upload-one-file-by-ftp-from-command-line

Comment: can you suggest how to use ssh command and telnet command

Comment: If you use `scp` then you are using ssh - also `rsync` which also uses ssh. Follow my first link to see how to use telnet. I would say that both `telnet` and `ftp` are horrible compared to `scp` or `rsync`, and above all insecure. `rsync` is the most powerful of all. But it's your choice!

Comment: Thank for your suggestion .. i wil use scp but am stuck with password ... for production its not asking for password where for another asking

Comment: If you have or can get `sshpass` then this can help. Example: `sshpass -p 'password' scp file.tar.gz root@xxx.xxx.xxx.194:/backup`

Comment: tar is for create, maintain, modify, and extract files that are archived in the tar format right but i need for copying file with providing password

Comment: my comment was not about `tar` but about using `sshpass`. The filename in the example just happens to end in `.tar`.